# How to read string with spaces without using fgets()

Tags: c, string

I want to read a substring from a string which contains integers as well as a string with spaces, such as this:

> 1 2 I'm gonna make him an offer he can't refuse

The string I need is:

> I'm gonna make him an offer he can't refuse

but I can't find a way to do it and I can't use fgets() because that way I would be reading the whole string...

Any tips?

Comment: What is wrong with using `fgets` and then trimming off those integers?

Comment: You should find a way to do it with `fgets`.

Comment: @SergeyL. How can I trim the integers? They're not necessarily a number between 0 and 9, so I can't use the indexes as they may vary

Comment: You can scan the characters one at a time and check if they are a digit or space and stop when you encounter the first non-digit. You could use `strtol` or `sscanf` to do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Although I would recommend using `fgets` and then trimming the string off you could give `scanf` a go.

```
scanf("%*d %*d %[^\n]", buffer);
```

Comment: Is it possible to overflow the buffer with this code?

Comment: Yes, this code is intended as a usecase example. There are safeguards you can put in against that. E.g. `%[^\n]` can bet set to a maximum buffer size. `%1024[^\n]`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
char st[100];
int count=0;
while(st[count]!='\n'){
    st[count]=getch();
    if(st[count]=='1' || ...)
         count--;
    count++;
}
st[count]='\n';
printf("%s", st);
```